# C# Update no datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Ola preciso de ajuda para gravar os dados que forem modificados na datagridview na minha base de dados, chamando o metodo.

Metodo onde gravo os novos dados na base de dados.
A informacao e carregada para a datagridview e preciso de pegar todas as mudancas em qualquer cela e fazer uodate na base de dados quando o botao for clicado.
Obrigado pela ajuda :)

```
public static DataTable UpdateClient(string fname, string lname, string email, string mobnum, string summary, double maxinv, double mininv)
{
    String query = "Update Client set First_Name=@fname, Last_Name=@lname, Email=@email, Mobile_Number=@mobile, Summary=@summary, Max_Investment=@maxinv, Min_Investment=@mininv WHERE Client_ID";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mobnum);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@summary", summary);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxinv", maxinv);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mininv", mininv);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: A minha pergunta e como atualizar a base de dados ao clicar no botao update que guardara a informacao da datagridview

Answer (score -2):

Ola, na sua query no final `WHERE Client_ID` creio que tenha que ser algo neste sentido: `WHERE Client_ID = @client_id`, além disso ao chamar o metodo, nenhum id esta sendo pedido, logo como pegara esse id para atualizar os dados corretamente?
quanto ao resto, vou deixar um link que mostra como fazer o que deseja.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters

Comment: Obrigado realmente faltava esta parte 'Client_ID = @client_id', quanto ao link eu preciso de um exemplo.